# Dynamic graphs,pieCharts,Bars etc

Tags: android

please help..I want to make an android application in which i get values from database and need to show them in graphical,piechart,bars etc format. what is the best way of approach? can i get some sample code of such appliactions..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some great suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org). It includes a bunch of chart types, a lot of demo code and is free to use for both free or commercial applications.

Regards,

Dan